# Why does Ubuntu 16.04.2 run two Xorg instances?

Tags: 16.04, xorg, gdm

I'm trying to track down some crashes with an NVIDIA GTX 750 Ti (but that's a question I'll ask later).  In doing so, I noticed that Ubuntu is running two Xorg instances:  the one I normally use on vt2 and one owned by gdm (uid 121) on vt7.  Is that normal?

Thanks!

```
user@pc:~$ ps aux | grep Xorg
root      1703  0.0  0.1 149864 44608 tty7     S+   Mar02   0:11 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt7 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/121/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3
root      1942  0.7  0.1 171108 54652 tty2     S+   Mar02  19:46 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1100/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3
```

More info:  It looks like the vt2 instance goes away when I log out, and the default log in screen is on vt7.  Once I log in, I get put in a session on vt2.  Maybe this is normal?

Comment: Xorg display on vt7 is the default, why are you using vt2, you must have started it, that wont kill the one on vt7.